# BigCommerce [{"status":415,"message":"The specified input content type is not valid."}]

Tags: json, postman, bigcommerce

Trying to create a product rule using Postman on `BigCommerce`. All my other queries to BC  work fine but on this one I receive the

```
[{"status":415,"message":"The specified input content type is not valid."}]
```

Doesn't seem to matter what is in the actual body, even if it is empty.

call: 
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/xxxxxxxxx/v2/products/34371/rules

headers:

> X-Auth-Client:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   X-Auth-Token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   Accept:application/json
>   Content-Type:application/json

Comment: Having an example of the body you are using for your api request would help others test and see if they get the same result

Answer (score 1):

I found that the issue was with Postman. 
Postman was changing Content-Type: application/json to multipart/form-data behind the scenes.